# Setting up Backbone app in different files using Coffeescript and CodeKit

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am using Backbone.js with Coffeescript via CodeKit tool.

I've been including everything in a single file so far. But I want to start separating them. Before getting into AMD and require.js, I wanted to try something simple.

For example, I wanted to follow what was suggested in

[Backbone.js:separate the view ,collection,model to different js file,they could't recognize each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646451/backbone-jsseparate-the-view-collection-model-to-different-js-file-they-could)

And since I am using CodeKit which has an option to "append" (or import) JS files referenced by others, I'm thinking this will nicely put everything into a single file.

So here is what I want to achieve.

- a View file in a separate file "View.coffee"
- a Route file in a separate file "App.coffee"

And have everything compile into App.js via CodeKit by "importing" the view file into App.coffee.

in my View, I have the following

```
$ ->

  class View extends Backbone.View

    el:"#view"

    initialize: =>
      console.log app
```

in my controller I have

```
$ ->

  class App extends Backbone.Router

    view : new View

    routes:
      "" : "home"

    search: =>
      console.log "hi"

  app = new App
  Backbone.history.start()
```

Now in my CodeKit, I imported "View.coffee" into "App.coffee" so that they are compiled into a single file.

[image: "App.coffee" has "View.coffee" imported]

When I run it, I get "View" is not defined.

Now, I tried a variety of combination here. For example, I tried "window.View" and "window.App" to assign them into the global name space, but that wasn't successful. I could make it so that App can read View, but I couldn't get View to read App.

What is the best way to set this up? or am I doing it right? Also attaching the final JS output.

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.1
(function() {
  var __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
    __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
    __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor; child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

  $(function() {
    var App, app;
    App = (function(_super) {

      __extends(App, _super);

      function App() {
        this.search = __bind(this.search, this);
        return App.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      }

      App.prototype.view = new View;

      App.prototype.routes = {
        "": "home"
      };

      App.prototype.search = function() {
        return console.log("hi");
      };

      return App;

    })(Backbone.Router);
    app = new App;
    return Backbone.history.start();
  });

  /* -------------------------------------------- 
       Begin View.coffee 
  --------------------------------------------
  */


  $(function() {
    var View;
    return View = (function(_super) {

      __extends(View, _super);

      function View() {
        this.initialize = __bind(this.initialize, this);
        return View.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      }

      View.prototype.el = "#view";

      View.prototype.initialize = function() {
        return console.log(app);
      };

      return View;

    })(Backbone.View);
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$ ->
  class View extends Backbone.View
    #...
```

You're wrapping your `View` definition inside a function (actually two functions: the `$()` call and the usual CoffeeScript wrapper function) so the `View` variable is not accessible to anything outside that function. Even if CodeKit is avoiding the outer CoffeeScript wrapper function, you still have the `$()` function that you're adding. The result is that your classes can't see each other.

The easiest solution is to declare an application level globally accessible namespace:

```
window.app = { }
```

and then declare your classes inside that namespace:

```
$ ->
  class app.View extends Backbone.View
    #...
```

Then you can refer to that view as `app.View` where ever you need it. Similar things will apply to your routers, models, and support classes.